# Cooking old beets

Tags: vegetables

I just harvested some beets from last year, they are red in the center and the rest is a yellow white color.  They are huge, so are they edible?

Comment: There may (or may not) be palatability/texture issues ("woody") but they should be *edible* - you just may find that you don't enjoy them much, depending just how far past their prime these are.

Comment: Hello Beet gardener! We specialize in giving clear solutions to clear-cut problems. "Are they edible" is a clear, answerable problem. "How to cook them" is not, there are tons of ways to cook beets, none better than the other. So I removed that part of your question, but the first part is fine. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the beets are safe to eat.  I happen to have some beets that have been in my fridge for about 3 months.  They are also big.  What I will do in the next couple of days is what I think you should do.  Clean them, cut off a bit of the top, about a half inch and the same with the bottom, then put them in foil, put a bit of canola oil and salt on them, wrap them tight, put on a pan, in preheated 400 degree F oven for about one hour, check at 45 minutes, then cook as needed 15-45 minutes more.  I don't know how big yours are and if you are a bit iffy then bake at 350 F or 375 F, same time.  Boiling is also a way to do it but baking brings out such a sweetness in the beets it is just an unbeatable way of cooking them for me.  Good Luck.

Comment: "un-beet-able" way of cooking them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Beets last ages if stored in cool conditions; if it isn't moldy and is still hard like a rock and not squishy, it should be completely safe.  If it is a gigantic beet, it's possible it might be woody, but that's a separate question from whether it is safe.

I agree with @user33210; baking beets is definitely the best way of cooking them and brings out their natural sweetness in a way that moist cooking methods cannot.  I always bake them with a little bit of salt and olive oil; just like baked potatoes.